# Compile errors when declaring and iterating over an array

Tags: fortran

Could you please help me to understand the error in this Fortran code?

```
program NAME
  implicit none
  real :: i, j(i)

  do i=1, 100
    j(i)=2*i
    write(*,*) i , j(i)
  end do
pause
end program
```

Comment: What *is* the problem? Are you getting an error? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong with that program, so please narrow down your question with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 main errors in this snippet:

1. You are declaring the variable `i` as `real`, but trying to use it as a dimension of another variable and as a index of a `do` loop - two contexts in that a `integer` type variable are mandatory.
2. When you declare a fixed-size array in the scope of the main program, its shape must be known at compile time. Instead, you are referring to another variable, `i`, whose vale is not known at compile time. If you know the size of the array will be 100, declare it as `j(100)`. If you don't want to hardcode the size everywhere, declare a constant and reference it.

Like:

```
integer, parameter :: n = 100
real :: j(n)
```

Or else, if you don't know the shape at compile time and want it to be decide at each program run, use a dynamic array (more info all over the web, e.g. [here](http://www.pcc.qub.ac.uk/tec/courses/f90/stu-notes/F90_notesMIF_11.html)).

3. The `pause` statement was deleted from the language since like... more than 20 years ago.